# Intraclass correlation and simulating data

Tags: correlation, simulation, intraclass-correlation

I will apologize in advance for this somewhat messy problem.  I am trying to take an ICC reported from a previously published manuscript and design a general simulation program.

Let's say the reported ICC for two observations was 0.90.  If we have another observation of which the value is 10, is it accurate to state that we would expect the range of the next value to be 9-11? ie. 10*.9 and 10*1.1

I understand this is not the conventional use of an ICC.  However, is treating the ICC this way for "guessing" the range of next observations appropriate at all?  Is there another calculation that may be more appropriate, knowing the prior knowledge I have to model this is limited?

Comment: It is not clear what you are asking...

Comment: ICC is a metric of rater agreement and can be considered a constant (for the sake of argument).  If rater 1 then gives a score of 10, can I state that the range of expected scores from rater 2 will be between 9-11?  I will modify the question if this is better.

Comment: For a general simulation approach to ICC, check out chapter 4 of this book: Headrick, T. C. (2010). Statistical simulation: Power method polynomials and other transformations.  Boca Raton, FL: Chapman & Hall.